# setTimeout function Object.assigns a variable - but mutations to variable carry back to original variable

Tags: node.js

Sorry for the obfuscated title, not sure how to describe this succinctly.

I've got a class running via NodeJS. Simplified, it looks something like this:

```
constructor(){
  // ...
  this.state = {
    gambits: []
  }

  this.render = this.render.bind(this)

  //...
  this.render()

}
```

I have websocket listeners that fire off functions to set updated data from database and put them in the this.state variable.

The idea is that the render function should run every so many seconds via setTimeout, and when it runs it grabs data
from this.state, creates a new object for me to work with. Everytime render runs it should grab this.state.gambits, loop through,
and copy in data from other objects in state. The render function looks something like this:

```
render(){

  let gambits = Object.assign([], this.state.gambits)
  .sort(() => { /* ... */ })
  .map(g => {
    // g looks like this
    // {
    //   id: 1,
    //   priority: 2,
    //   enabled: true,
    //   conditions: [ 2 ],
    //   reactions: [ 1, 2 ]
    // }

    // For each gambit that's enabled and configured...
    if (g.enabled && g.conditions.length && g.reactions.length) {
      // grab the conditions...

      console.log('conditions: ', g.conditions)
      g.conditions = g.conditions.map((c) => {
        return this.state.conditions.find((con) => {
          return con.id = c
        })
      })

      return g
    } else {
      return null
    }

  })

  clearTimeout(this.timeout)
  this.timeout = setTimeout(this.render, 5000)

}
```

You can see how I use .map() to loop through the gambits array, the g.condition array contains id numbers that match condition objects id numbers.

I find the condition object with the matching id with .find() and I return the condition object that matches.

The first time through the render function it all appears to work as expected.

Subsequent excutions of render give me weird results.

First time through, I see what I expect:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    group: 1,
    priority: 99999,
    enabled: true,
    conditions: [
      {
        id: 5,
        group: '1',
        expressions: [
          {
            data: { deviceId: '13', dataPointIndex: '0' },
            operator: '>=',
            value: '75',
            plateValue: '0'
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    reactions: [
      {
        id: 5,
        group: '1',
        expression: { deviceId: '13', outputIndex: '0', value: 'true' }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And, second time through:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    group: 1,
    priority: 99999,
    enabled: true,
    conditions: [
      <ref *1> {          // <<<<---------- ????? <ref *1> ?
        id: [Circular *1],
        group: '1',
        expressions: [
          {
            data: { deviceId: '13', dataPointIndex: '0' },
            operator: '>=',
            value: '75',
            plateValue: '0'
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    reactions: [
      <ref *2> {
        id: [Circular *2],
        group: '1',
        expression: { deviceId: '13', outputIndex: '0', value: 'true' }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So I added a `console.log('conditions: ', g.conditions)` in the midst of the .map() before any mutations to the g.conditions.

The first time through, I see what I expect:

```
conditions: [ 5 ]
```

second time through I see

```
conditions:  [
  <ref *1> {
    id: [Circular *1],
    group: '1',
    expressions: [ [Object] ]
  }
]
```

ok, so it has to be that SOMEHOW this.state.gambits is either getting updated, or I'm referencing the same object?

I use `Object.assign([], this.state.gambits)` for the explicit purpose of not referencing the `this.state.gambits` array. But it still seems to be mutating it. Very confusing.

Any ideas why this is happening or what else I need to do to fix this? I'm super confused.

Thanks

Comment: Haven't read the question completely but i guess you are expecting `Object.assign` to make a deep copy. It makes a shallow copy, so in the case of objects inside the `gambits` array, it will copy their references.

Comment: Interestingly enough, adding a ` g = Object.assign({}, g)` inside of the .map((g) => { /**/ }) function seems to fix this problem. But I can't wrap my head around why...

Comment: Yes Yousaf, I think you are spot on....

Comment: I think I know what to do. Go ahead and add your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks

Comment: @John Yes that `Object.assign({}, g})` within `map` will make a shallow copy of that particular object. And if the values of `g` are only simple types (numbers, strings, booleans) it may solve your problem. But if the properties of `g` are themselves again objects or arrays (like the `conditions`), you will just push your issue one level deeper ...

Comment: Yes @derpirscher that's exactly it. I figure I have 2 options - Either create a new array and push data to it from inside the .map(), or add new keys to objects only so as to not distort the existing structure. Thanks for your insights!

Comment: The simplest solution for creating a real deep copy can also be `let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original))` this makes a really deep copy where none of the objects has any references to each other. You can also do that at too level